# Problem w/state of a vue data object in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am updating my original vue project and am getting an error w/data object **sports_feeds_boxscores_***. The site has three tabs to pull down scores for the three major leagues. I am adding the player stats for each game now. I first did baseball and all worked fine. Now I am doing football and the problem arises. I have three objects setup for the stats for each league. The nfl also contains an object with the three days of the week they play. What is happening is the stats for Sunday get pulled down ok but then Thursday's stats which should only be one game instead has all sunday's games plus the one thursday game. And then Monday has both Sunday & Thursdays results in it besides Mondays. I have made all the components separate as well as three separate data objects for the component props. And if I first click the nfl tab and then go to the mlb tab all results from nfl data object are in **sports_feeds_boxscores_mlb**. I setup a site [here](http://vue-trouble.surge.sh) to better understand whats going on in using Vue.js devtools. Here is the pertinent code:

index.html:

```
<component
            v-if="currentTabComponent === 'tab-mlb'"
            v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"
            v-bind:props_league_data="sports_feeds_data"
            v-bind:props_league_standings="standings"
            v-bind:props_baseball_playoffs="baseball_playoffs"
            v-bind:props_end_of_season="end_of_season[this.currentTab.toLowerCase()]"
            v-bind:props_box_game_scores_mlb="sports_feeds_boxscores_mlb"
            class="tab"
          >
          </component>

          <component
            v-if="currentTabComponent === 'tab-nfl'"
            v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"
            v-bind:props_league_data="sports_feeds_data"
            v-bind:props_league_data_nfl="nfl_feeds"
            v-bind:props_league_standings="standings"
            v-bind:props_nfl_playoffs="nfl_playoffs"
            v-bind:props_end_of_season="end_of_season[this.currentTab.toLowerCase()]"
            v-bind:props_box_game_scores_nfl="sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl"
            class="tab"
          >
          </component>
```

vue.js:

```
data() {
    return {
      sports_feeds_boxscores_mlb: null,
      sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl: {
        sun: null,
        mon: null,
        thurs: null
      },
      sports_feeds_boxscores_nba: null,
        etc

/* Component Code */
// First let's get the Game and BoxScores Data
        const nflScores = async () => {
          this.nfl_feeds.sunday_data = await getScores(
            nflDate.sundayDate,
            config
          );

          this.nfl_feeds.thurs_data = await getScores(
            nflDate.thursdayDate,
            config
          );

          this.nfl_feeds.mon_data = await getScores(nflDate.mondayDate, config);

          // Next we need the gameid's to retrieve the game boxscores for each day
          this.nfl_feeds.sunday_data.forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (item.isCompleted === "true") {
              nflGameIDs.sunday[index] = item.game.ID;
            }
          });

          this.nfl_feeds.thurs_data.forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (item.isCompleted === "true") {
              nflGameIDs.thursday[index] = item.game.ID;
            }
          });

          this.nfl_feeds.mon_data.forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (item.isCompleted === "true") {
              nflGameIDs.monday[index] = item.game.ID;
            }
          });

// Check if boxscores have been retrieved on previous tab click for each day
          // if not retrieve the boxscores
          this.sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl.sun =
            this.sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl.sun ||
            (await getBoxScores(nflGameIDs.sunday, url, params));


          this.sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl.thurs =

            (await getBoxScores(nflGameIDs.thursday, url, params));

          this.sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl.mon =
            this.sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl.mon ||
            (await getBoxScores(nflGameIDs.monday, url, params));

}; /* End nflScores Async function */
```

getBoxScores.js:

```
try {
  const getBoxScores = async (gameIDs, myUrl, params) => {
    gameIDs.forEach(function(item) {
      promises.push(
        axios({
          method: "get",
          headers: {
            Authorization:
              "Basic &&*&&^&&=="
          },
          url: myUrl + item,
          params: params
        })
      );
    });

    // axios.all returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed
    // as an iterable have resolved. This single promise, when resolved, is passed to the
    // "then" and into the "values" parameter.
    await axios.all(promises).then(function(values) {
      boxScores = values;
    });
    console.log(`boxScores is ${boxScores.length}`)
    return boxScores;
  };

  module.exports = getBoxScores;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

I have split up all the sports_feeds_boxscores objects and at a loss as to why they are sharing state??? Sorry for verbosity of the question but it is somewhat complex. That is why I provided the site where you can see devtools that for instance **this.sports_feeds_boxscores_nfl.thurs** has 14 elements instead of one after the call to API. And if mlb tab is clicked after nfl tab then mlb results include the nfl results. I would really appreciate help in figuring this out. Thanks in advance...
**Update:**
I have added getBoxScores.js cause it seems as if I am returning the extra stats from this call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my bad. I didnt realize I had created a closure in getBoxScores.js:

```
let boxScores = [];
let promises = [];

try {
  const getBoxScores = async (gameIDs, myUrl, params) => {
   gameIDs.forEach(function(item) {
      promises.push(
        axios({
          method: "get",
          headers: {
            Authorization:
              "Basic &&^^&^&&^FGG="
          },
          url: myUrl + item,
          params: params
        })
      );
    });
```

Moving declarations inside async function quickly solved trouble. URRRRGGGHHH!!!